# Story where radically different cultures live together and are defined by rulesets, some choose not to see each other, a house is used as a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think this novel came out in the 2000s.  There are many cultures that live close together but are very different, for example some pretend to be pre-industrial.  One of the main characters is a youth who grew up in a pretend pre-industrial society and is now exploring the rest of the solar system? ring-world?

Each culture experiences their own reality that is defined by a ruleset.  One of the rulesets becomes aggressively self-propagating and this is the problem that drives the plot.

At some point a tumbling house, just a normal house, is used to travel across space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this review](http://www.strangehorizons.com/reviews/2006/03/lady_of_mazes_b.shtml), I think this is *Lady of Mazes* by Karl Schroeder. The review mentions multiple cultures in the same space, but kept separate:

> the venue is an AI-built ringworld near Jupiter, called Teven Coronal.
>   Schroeder foresees a future in which entire
>   realities—"manifolds"—inhabit the same physical space, and where there
>   is little delineation remaining between the experience of the real and
>   the experience of the virtual. The cultures of each manifold are kept
>   discrete from one another by tech locks, the implications of which
>   give the book its philosophical underpinning. The book's heroine,
>   Livia Kodaly, is a diplomat between these virtual worlds.

And it also mentions a flying house:

> Livia and Aaron are somewhat less feeble than those around them and
>   take it upon themselves, along with Qiingi, to leave their ringworld
>   in a flying house (which I want), to go to the neighbouring
>   Archipelago and endeavour to discover the nature of the invasion and
>   whether or not it can be stopped.

Comment: That was it, thank you.